# Evernote as ACTION_SEND Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, evernote

when i call Intent

```
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType(MIME_TYPE_TEXT);
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
```

...

```
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), chooserDialogTitle);
```

i can choose Evernote (when it is installed), 
then i get the LOGIN or REGISTER SCREEN from Evernote

when i click on the back-button my app will be closed as well, all other choosable intents (GoogleMail, WhatsUp, SMS and so on) only close itself

i think they override the backbutton. is this possible? got anyone the same problem?

Comment: have u tried other apps' Share to function? I tried on Twitter, when use share to, select evernote and press back button, it will close Evernote only.

Comment: did you got the login/register screen as well or was you already logged in? Evernote 4.3.5 with Motorola XOOM Android 4.0.4

Comment: I've logged in already, and I'm using Galaxy Nexus under Android 4.1, Evernote 4.3.5

Comment: i tried this as logged in user and it works... seems to be only if you not logged in

Comment: What do you mean by "when i click on the back-button my app will be closed as well"?

Comment: if i want to share something, i can choose with witch app i want to share my content. If all is done i can see my app again: example appA shares my highscore. i choose whatsUp to share. so if everything is fine i will go to appA again when all is done. but with evernote i come to the homescreen, and when i start my appA again i see the evernote Login again (activity is still active) and i can only choose force appA to stop

Comment: Mario, I sent this to our QA to investigate reproducibility and get it assigned to an engineer.